# Assert alternative (or)

Tags: java, hamcrest, rest-assured

I have an endpoint which returns either `true` or `false`. Is it somehow possible to tell `Hamcrest` with `RestAssured` to check whether there exist one of mentioned two ? I've already tried `containsString`, `hasItems` etc, but none of them works **i.e it checks for both of them**.

```
get("http://localhost:8080/trueOrFalse")
        .then()
        .body(hasItems("true", "false")); // TRUE or FALSE not both
```

Comment: Can you post what you are doing? It looks straightforward to me, but I'm not sure if I fully understood your concern(s) so I want to make sure what you asked is what I'm thinking it could be

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ I've updated my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `either()` method on the CombinableMatcher class.

**Example**

```
assertThat(result, either(is(true)).or(is(false)));
```